# querySelectorAll not working with nested ULs

Tags: javascript, css, html-lists, selectors-api

I am seeing something weird with querySelectorAll being called on nested UL objects. Can somebody confirm that this is a bug, or am I thinking about it wrong?

Given this html:

```
<ul class="first">
<li>
    <ul class="second">
        <li class="third"></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I am finding that using the selector 'ul.second li' with querySelectorAll returns li.third even when called like so:

```
var ulSecond = document.querySelectorAll('ul')[1];
ulSecond.querySelectorAll('ul.second li'). // result is li.third
```

Am I crazy? I've tried a bunch of other cases and they all work correctly but this doesn't.

Here's a fiddle of what I'm trying to do.

https://jsfiddle.net/gh9j04v5/

Comment: That's exactly the behaviour I'd expect. What would you expect to happen?

Comment: It is doing exactly what you ask. Computers don't make mistakes :)

Comment: That's what the selector you passed in means; what end result were you hoping for?

Comment: How is it not the same as this jQuery('ul').eq(1).find('ul.second li')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion is that calling `querySelectorAll('ul.second li')` on the `<ul class="second">` is returning you `<li class="third"></li>` when you expect it to be empty.

When you execute `querySelectorAll` it searches the element's descendants for elements that match the query, as the entire query.

So for your example, it finds any descendant of "second" that "is an LI element with ul.second as an ancestor".

It doesn't sequentially find each element in the query like

```
elem.querySelectorAll('ul.second')...forEach(querySelectorAll('li'))
```

or "find all ul.second under elem and then find each li under those"

You can see this behavior on any page by using a query like

```
document.body.querySelectorAll('body div')
```

which will return all the `div`s in a page despite the query being issued on `body`

Comment: That is sort of my confusion. I was expecting it to act like this. jQuery('ul').eq(1).find('ul.second li')  Thanks for your response.